# Chart data isnt showing in the canvas but console.log shows the expected values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So its my first time using chartjs. Im trying to use stacked horizontal charts. I have 2 values which I calculate using some sort function. I do console.logs to check if values are correct and they are both as expected. But when i try to update the chart only the first value shows in the canvas, and the 2nd value shows 0 but my chart gridlines adjusts correctly. Im not too sure what is happening.

Here is where I declare my chart data

```
          var eventDays1 = 0;
          var eventDays2 = 0;
          var barChartData = {
            labels: ['Events'],
            datasets: [{
              label: eventName1,
              backgroundColor: "#E5C1BD",   
              data:[eventDays1]
            }, {
              label: eventName2,
              backgroundColor: "#D2D0BA",
              data:[eventDays2]
            }
            ]};
```

Here is the actual chart

```
            myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'horizontalBar',
              data: barChartData,
              options: {
                          legend: {
                              display: true,
                              labels: {
                                  fontColor: 'black',
                                  fontSize:20,
                              }

                          },
                responsive: true,
                          scales: {
                          xAxes: [{ stacked: false,
                                  ticks:{
                                      fontColor:"black"
                                  },
                              scaleLabel: {
                                  display: true,
                                  labelString: 'Days',
                                  fontColor:"black"
                              }


                          }],
                          yAxes: [{
                                  ticks: {
                                      beginAtZero:true,
                                      max:365,
                                      fontColor:"black"
                                  },
                                  stacked: true,

                          }]
                    }

              },
            });
```

Here is my updateChart function that I call. Note that the console.logs
are values that I expect already.

```
      function updateChart(newList){

          eventDays1 = newList[0];

          if(newList.length == 2){
            eventDays2 = newList[1];

          }

          myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = eventDays1;
          myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[1] = eventDays2;

          console.log("data 1 "+eventDays1);
          console.log("data 2 "+eventDays2);


          myBarChart.update();  
      }
```